# If a company I bought stock in was de-listed but is now listed again under a new symbol, what happened to my shares?

Tags: shares

I bought some shares from a company that had one of the first accounting make up scandals. After that the company was forbidden to operate for some years. I've forgotten of those shares. But now I saw they´re again at Nasdaq with another symbol. Have I lost my original shares?

Comment: Did the company have to file for bankruptcy and reorganize itself? If so, then the shares may be worthless.

Comment: How did you hold the shares? In a brokerage account? The broker may be able to advise you of the status of your older shares.

Comment: What is the company?

Answer (score 2):

If the company went bankrupt, the issued public shares that were outstanding at the time most likely were voided, in which case your shares are most definitely gone.  The company might have done a new stock issuance coming out of bankruptcy with a different symbol, and while it could be substantially the same company, it doesn't mean much for you.  It's unfortunate this may be the case, but it is one of the risks of investing.